# How i can get pair contact price?

Tags: web3.py

For example, I have a contract address for a pair of WETH/USDC: 0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640
how can i get the price of this pair using web3.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from web3 import Web3

## Connect to a local or remote Ethereum node

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

## The address of the WETH/USDC contract

contract_address = '0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640'

## The ABI (Application Binary Interface) of the contract

contract_abi = [abi_json_string]

## Instantiate the contract object

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

## Call the 'price0CumulativeLast' function to get the price of WETH in wei

price_weth = contract.functions.price0CumulativeLast().call()

## Convert the price from wei to ether

price_weth_ether = w3.fromWei(price_weth, 'ether')

## Call the 'price1CumulativeLast' function to get the price of USDC in wei

price_usdc = contract.functions.price1CumulativeLast().call()

## Convert the price from wei to ether

price_usdc_ether = w3.fromWei(price_usdc, 'ether')

## Calculate the price of WETH/USDC

price_pair = price_weth_ether / price_usdc_ether

print('WETH/USDC price:', price_pair)

note that the ABI is not provided in this example, you need to get the ABI from the contract developer or by using a tool like remix to get the ABI.

Also, this is just an example, the actual price calculation will depend on the design of the smart contract.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an API from like binance or something to get the prices. If you were doing it onchain then Chainlink Price Feeds